# Generalization and Proof of Littlewood's Conjecture

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

Does anyone know of the validity of this ["Proof"](http://article.sapub.org/10.5923.j.ajms.20170703.04.html) of the Generalization and Proof of Littlewood's Conjecture ? Do you know this Kaveh Mozafari?

Comment: Have you tried reading the proof? A first glance at it suggested there was nothing terribly deep being used, so it should be readable. Carefully reading it might provide a more reliable assessment than knowing the breadth of the author's circle of acquaintances.

Comment: I was wondering if anyone read, do not waste time with any nonsense.